# Expressjs - what is a router Layer

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to understand the ExpressJS Routers better.

I see in the source code that there is a [seperate module for a Layer](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js) that gets used with the router. It seems to be doing some basic RegEx operations for parameters.

I've noticed [Koa-router](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/tree/master/lib) uses this module too.

What is the layer doing for the router?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a further look at the source and have determined this:

Each instance of a `router()` has a stack property which is an Array > `router.stack[]`.
Whenever you call `router.route()` or `router.use()` a new instance of `Layer()` is pushed into the stack.
`Layer()` does the actual handling of the `error, req, res, next` set.

I'd love some feedback or better insight to this.